# How to make Class.clone or Class.dup work in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, clone

I have a model called `Client` and I would like to clone it in certain cases where clients (the real world kind) have modifications that require class level changes.

For example, if I have:

```
class Client
  set_table_name :clients

  def some_method
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

Then if I have the following:

```
module ClientA
  def some_method
    puts "World"
  end
end
```

I would expect that I could clone (or dup) the class, then include the module to overwrite the method `some_method`.

But here's what happens in my production console:

```
> CA = Client.dup
> CA.singleton_class.send(:include, ClientA) # Or just CA.send(:include, ClientA)
> client = CA.new
> client.some_method
=> "Hello" # Expected "World"
```

Is there a trick to this?

Comment: not really an answer, but what do you mean by "my client require class specific changes" ? i know ruby is nice and flexible, but if you dynamically create a new class every time your client changes his mood and asks you to "change the behavior of the software, but only for client X", you're more or less asking for trouble... and will end up with a pile of undebuggable crapware.

Comment: Yep, I know. I'm not a fan of the request, but am trying to find some elegant way to do this. Have not discovered anything really as of yet (not sure I will).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Client.dup` use `Class.new(Client)`, which subclasses Client.

If you're trying to avoid that, this seems to work with `Client.dup`:

```
CA.send(:define_method, :some_method) do 
  puts "World"
end
```

Comment: That worked! Can you explain a little of the mechanics behind this?

Comment: Class.new(parent) declares a subclass of the parent. I'm not sure what Class#dup would do under the hood...

Comment: I would recommend moving that comment into the answer to avoid flagging (due to very small body, lacking explanation, etc).

Comment: Only problem here, and it's my fault for not specifying, but I'm trying to avoid subclassing. I'll select this answer anyway, as it does get the job done -- just not the way I was hoping. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to override specific classes with a module's data, you want to extend it.

```
client = Client.new
client.extend(ClientA)
client.some_method
=> "World"
```

You can see it work here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/7621e